# Tivoli Data Protection for Exchange Restore Error ACN0101E Invalid argument

Tags: exchange-2010, tivoli, tsm

I'm trying to restore a single mail database into a recovery database on exchange 2010 using a differential backup from 10/04/2013.  I have created a recovery database in exchange 2010 named RDB1.  I have tried using the gui it fails 0 seconds into the restore with no error just a status of failed so im trying the command line.

a query of TSM backups returns

```
tdpexcc query tsm * /all

IBM Tivoli Storage Manager for Mail:
Data Protection for Microsoft Exchange Server
Version 6, Release 4, Level 1.0
(C) Copyright IBM Corporation 1998, 2013. All rights reserved.

Querying Tivoli Storage Manager server for a list of database backups, please wait...


Connecting to TSM Server as node 'EXCH_TDP_EXCH'...
Connecting to Local DSM Agent 'EXCH'...
Using backup node 'EXCH_TDP_EXCH'...


  Exchange Server  : EXCH

  Database         : Employee (A-L) Mailbox Database 3

     Backup Date        Size     S Fmt  Type   Loc        Object Name       
-------------------  ----------- - ---- ----   --- -------------------------
.... removed unwanted database backups for clarity....

09/28/2013 02:02:06      80.37GB I VSS  full   Srv 20130928020206 
                         13.36GB                   Logs
                         67.01GB                   File
09/29/2013 02:02:14     927.00MB I VSS  diff   Srv 20130929020214 
                        927.00MB                   Logs
09/30/2013 02:02:10   1,850.00MB I VSS  diff   Srv 20130930020210 
                      1,850.00MB                   Logs
10/01/2013 02:03:09   4,140.00MB I VSS  diff   Srv 20131001020309 
                      4,140.00MB                   Logs
10/02/2013 02:04:01   6,169.00MB I VSS  diff   Srv 20131002020401 
                      6,169.00MB                   Logs
10/04/2013 02:02:09   9,737.00MB I VSS  diff   Srv 20131004020209 

.... removed unwanted database backups for clarity....
```

To restore the Diff from 10/04/13 i first need the full from 9/28/13. 
All my attempts to restore fails as follows with an ACN0101E Invalid argument error.

```
TDPEXCC RESTore "Employee (A-L) Mailbox Database 3" FULL /INTODB=RDB1  /object=20130928020206

IBM Tivoli Storage Manager for Mail:
Data Protection for Microsoft Exchange Server
Version 6, Release 4, Level 1.0
(C) Copyright IBM Corporation 1998, 2013. All rights reserved.

ACN0101E Invalid argument: RESTore Employee (A-L) Mailbox Database 3
```

I have read the docs at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tsminfo/v6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itsm.mail.exc.doc%2Fdpe_ref_cmd_restore.html and my syntax looks correct.